# Can anyone clarify something about the sys module and the nature of variables?

Tags: python, argv, sys

Its simple.sys.argv is a list which I assigned to a variable. Sys.argv varies with user input. Would the variable change with it as well? I know this like going deep into tiny details but i really could use some help.

```
import sys
list=sys.argv
```

Comment: After that point the variable `list` will refer to the arguments from the command line that are contained in `sys.argv`. No gory details here, it is a simple variable assignment.

Comment: would it change with extra arguments added to the sys.argv?

Comment: would that override the old list variable to a new one?

Comment: It is a simple assignment and just behaves that way. The previous value of `list` is forgotten and `sys.argv` is unchanged. What are you expecting here?

Comment: `sys.argv` itself is a list, so why bother storing it in a separate variable for lists

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable will not change unless you reassign it to `sys.argv`. Variables do not magically change based on their assignment unless they share memory locations. `sys.argv` is a list (mutable) so there is no reason it should or would share a memory address with `list`.

Which brings us to another point: if `sys.argv` is already a list, why would you store it in a different list variable? (hint: you wouldn't)

Comment: i just was too lazy to constantly write sys.argv XD

Comment: ah, ok. If my answer helped, would you mind upvoting and accepting?

Comment: it actually did but im still new to upvotes and stuff can u tell me how?

Comment: There are two arrows next to the score of a post, and the one pointing up upvotes it

Comment: Once you hit 125 rep, you’ll unlock the ability to downvote